# iframe for YouTube embed: lazy loading doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, iframe, cross-browser

Lazy loading is supported in Firefox since version 75: https://caniuse.com/#feat=loading-lazy-attr

I found that this works on Firefox for lazy loading of images. However, YouTube embedding in an iframe, it doesn't work. I ensured that the video is long way below the fold. Even then, the iframe is loaded upfront. This is the HTML for the iframe:

```
<iframe loading="lazy" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/iQBat7e0MQs" allowfullscreen="" width="480" height="270"></iframe>
```

On Chrome, lazy loading works as expected for the same web page (on my localhost).

Comment: Not sure what's causing this, but I have the same issue.

Comment: It‘s stated on caniuse on hover in an explanation that „Firefox only supports lazy loading for images“. You would need to use a polyfill like one of which I‘ve developed to achieve this: https://github.com/mfranzke?tab=repositories&q=Loading-attribute&type=&language=&sort=